# Rails & Devise: destroy_user_session_path going to Users#Show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Pretty standard link:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path(current_user) %></li>
```

rake routes:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
```

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks", sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

users/sessions_controller.rb:

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

```
  def destroy
    binding.pry
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully Logged Out"
    redirect_to new_session_path
  end

end
```

binding.pry is not even being called. The link takes me to the url `/users/sign_out` but the view is Users#show.

Any ideas?

Comment: please show the controller function that handles the session#destroy

Comment: Hey @hamitron I added some edits to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destroy action requires the DELETE HTTP verb as shown in your `rake routes` output.

You need to add `method: :delete` to the end of your link helper, otherwise the link will produce a GET request.